# Correct use of typeOf for string

Tags: javascript, string, types

Can someone tell me if this is the correct way to do a typeOf check in JavaScript?

```
if ((typeof str === "string") && (str.toLowerCase() == "true")) return true;
```

I find it a bit odd that string needs to be in quotes I thought it would be *String* without any quotes. I'm sure I read somewhere that there there is a right and wrong way to do this.
Thank you.

Comment: Your code seems OK, typeof returns a string. [Documentation](http://www.w3resource.com/javascript/operators/typeof.php)

Comment: [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) (used as an operator or as a function) returns a string, so yes, the quotes are required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Developper Mozilla developper network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) you can use simple quote to define the type you are looking for.

Also it lists the good and the bad way to achieve what you talking about:

```
// Strings
typeof "" === 'string';
typeof "bla" === 'string';
typeof (typeof 1) === 'string'; // typeof always return a string
typeof String("abc") === 'string'; // but never use this form!
```

Answer (score 1):

This explains the use of "typeof":
http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/determinevar2.shtml
I think you are confusing it with instanceof in Java, in which you will me matching it with the String class.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `String` in if statement, you can use constructor. It would be like this:

```
if ((str.constructor == String)) ...
```

Check http://jsfiddle.net/sCU3M/

But using `typeof str === "string"` is also correct.

Answer (score 1):

The "typeof" function returns a string and that is why you need to check the result as a string (with quotes). However, you can simply write the entire condition as:

```
return ((typeof str === "string") && (str.toLowerCase() == "true"));
```